# Calling methods of existing JRuby objects from Java

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I'm trying to provide a JRuby callback to my Java class, so I can get notified when an event happens in the Java part of my program ([a OrientDB Java Hook](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Java-Hooks.html)).

The JRuby wiki offers [examples](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyAndJavaCodeExamples#Java_ttCallRubyjavatt) demonstrating how to load JRuby files and run them in Java, but in my case, the Ruby codes are already in the same JVM, and I just need to send signals to existing Ruby objects.

Assume I have the ruby class loaded in memory:

```
class A
  def self.b
    puts 'ruby called'
  end
end
```

How should I call `A.b` from my Java method?

Comment: could you clarify how you're setup the JRuby interpreter ... it's not clear whether you're using the embed APIs.

Comment: @kares hi, I'm running the whole app with jruby 9.0.0.0 and using LockJar + com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory in JRuby to get an embeded OrientDB.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can just use JRuby in this case.

For the OrientDB embed example, instead of a Java class, I can pass a ruby class

```
class H < com.orientechnologies.orient.core.hook.ORecordHookAbstract
  def onRecordAfterCreate(r)  
    puts r
  end  
end
```

to the API and let Java code call Ruby.

[Relevant gist](https://gist.github.com/pinyin/c90e17a11a11b34725ac)